# Why GetProcAddress doesn't work?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, name-decoration

First, I create a simple dll called `SimpleDll.dll`, its head file:

```
// SimpleDll.h
#ifdef MYLIBAPI
#else
#define MYLIBAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

MYLIBAPI int Add(int a. int b);
```

its source code:

```
// SimpleDll.c
#include <windows.h>

#define MYLIBAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#include "SimpleDll.h"    

int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Then I call it in another project, and it works fine:

```
// TestSimpleDll.c
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "SimpleDll.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "SimpleDll.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("%d", Add(10, 30));    // Give the expected result 40
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I call `GetProcAddress` to get it's address, it doesn't work!

```
// TestSimpleDll2.c
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "SimpleDll.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "SimpleDll.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("%d", Add(10, 30));    // Give the expected result 40
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleA("SimpleDll.dll");    // hModule is found
    PROC add_proc       = GetProcAddress(hModule, "Add");     // but Add is not found !
    //  add_proc is NULL!
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help.  (PS: I use VS2010 on Windows7)
Update:
This is what the depedency walker show for the `SimpleDll.dll` file:

[image]

Comment: 1) Why are you explicitly using the ANSI version of `GetModuleHandle`? 2) If going the widechar route you should wrap your string literals in `_T("")`

Comment: your names are mangled, use a .def file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a .def file if you want to export the name for GetProcAddress.  Otherwise you will have to deal with c++ name [mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and with symbol decorations.

You can avoid mangling by declaring your function as `extern "C"`, but the only way to avoid decorations is to use a .DEF file.

One more thing - in Dependency walker - use F10 to toggle between decorated and undecorated names.

Comment: The `extern "C"` modifier doesn't avoid name mangling, it just simplifies it.  `cdecl` functions will still have an underscore prefixed, and `stdcall` functions will have (`@`+the stack size of parameters) suffixed.  You're correct that a .DEF file is the way to eliminate mangling entirely.

Comment: how to avoid name mangling for Constructor of a class in an explicit Dll?

Answer (score 2):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is an excellent tool for troubleshooting DLL issues like this.

I'm assuming you are compiling the DLL as C code. Otherwise, C++ performs name mangling that would cause problems.

To avoid name mangling simply wrap the export definition in extern "C".

```
extern "C" {
    MYLIBAPI int Add(int a. int b);
}
```

Comment: Check to make sure the export (i.e. Add) is named correctly. If it has strange characters in front of it, then that is an issue that can be addressed.

Comment: Hi, I just uploaded a screen shot of what dependency walker show for the `SimpleDll.dll`, is there something wrong?

Comment: @wong2: Definitely a C++ name mangling issue.  Only mangled names contain parameter type information, which is clearly visible in the screenshot.  Follow @John's advice and use a .DEF file (and maybe also `extern "C"`).