# Calling Dlls on Ruby (not the Windows API)

Tags: c++, ruby, winapi

I'm at a Ruby enviroment where I can't load C extensions, just pure-ruby code. I can't use RubyInline, FFI or Win32OLE, only one way to load an external code: Win32API. But how can I compile a C++ code that can be required by the ruby? I tried with these codes, but raised an error:

test.cpp

```
static int add(int a, int b) // I tried without static too
{
  return a + b;
}
```

compile

```
g++ --shared test.cpp -o test.dll
```

main.rb

```
Win32API.new('test.dll', 'add', 'II', 'I').call(1, 2) # => should return 3
```

error message

```
RunTimeError
GetProcAddress: add or addA
```

versions:

```
Ruby 1.8.1
GCC 4.5.2 (tdm-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a .DEF file.  See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684737/why-getprocaddress-doesnt-work/5684867#5684867)