# Calling a DLL explicitly

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, dll

Can anyone tell me why my SimpleTest application does not display "Test"?
The DLL loads successfully, I just don't get any console output.

**SimpleDLL.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SimpleDLL.h"

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int Test()
{
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**SimpleDLL.h**

```
#ifndef _DLL_TUTORIAL_H_
#define _DLL_TUTORIAL_H_
#include <iostream>

#if defined DLL_EXPORT
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DECLDIR int Test();

#endif
```

**SimpleTest.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

typedef int (*TestFunc)();

int main()
{
    TestFunc _TestFunc;
    HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary( _T("SimpleDLL.dll"));

    if (hInstLibrary)
    {
        _TestFunc = (TestFunc)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "Test");
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "DLL Failed To Load!" << std::endl;
    }

    if (_TestFunc)
    {
        _TestFunc();
    }

    FreeLibrary(hInstLibrary);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't get any console output, or it says "DLL Failed To Load!"? Have you stepped through your code with the debugger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why GetProcAddress doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684737/why-getprocaddress-doesnt-work) Short answer: your problem comes from function name [mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B).

Comment: Is `GetProcAdress()` successful? It would be unknown to you if it failed given the current code.

Comment: Your problem is name mangling. Take a look at the answer Frederic linked to.

Comment: @ObscureRobot - I state that the dll loads successfully, and I don't gat any output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare `extern "C"` before `__declspec(...)`. This is because C++ adds name decoration when you export a C++ function, and you need to declare it as a C function to have the function `Test` exported as just "Test"

Comment: Could you also add a note about his missing error handling of the `GetProcAddress` function?

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP intends to do, but normally, you'd check the return value of `LoadLibrary` and **return** (or raise appropriate exception) if it fails, and then check the return value of `GetProcAddress` and do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. A couple of other questions please before I mark as answered, I used the same code above but with implicit linking, and it all worked fine, not sure why it didn't only when i use explicit linking. Is this called "name mangling" as mentioned above? Thanks

Comment: @pingu If you are using implicit linking, then the compiler is also looking for the mangled version of the function name than just "Test". Since the exported symbol is also mangled by default, the compiler would be able to find it and link it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As has been stated by JoesphH you need `extern "C"` to prevent name mangling. In addition to this do not have either of the following compiler switches specified:

- Gz `__stdcall` calling convention: "Test" would be exported as    `Test@0`
- Gr `__fastcall` caling convention: "Test" would be exported as `@Test@0`

*Note: I think last symbol is dependent on compiler version but is still not just "Test".*

Also, as per my comment check return value from `GetProcAddress()` and use the value of `GetLastError()` to obtain reason for failure if NULL was returned.